# How to add Components defined in merge module to setup project feature using wix

Tags: wix

I have created a 1 merge modules and i has all the components as a separate wix file , and i grouped all the components as component group.but i am unable to add the component group to the setup project.Can any one help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The components of a merge module are added to a feature using the `MergeRef` attribute. See this [example](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html). You don't refer to the components directly. And, a ComponentGroup is a WiX-only concept that is "erased" by the WiX linker when making a Windows Installer merge module.

FWIW, I've never created a merge module and I don't like having to consume them. Also, as an end-user, I prefer third-party components that I can update separately from an application. If you are creating a common set of components for internal consumption, consider a WiX Library (wixlib) project instead. Or, if creating it as a redistributable, consider a complete setup (MSI or EXE) that application distributors can use in a bootstrapper (e.g., WiX Bootstrapper).

See this [article](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/10/10/what-are-.wixlibs-and-why-would-you-use-them) by Rob Mensching for a short comparison of wixlibs and merge modules.